# access native windows api from javaScript

Tags: javascript, native

is it possible to access native windows api from javascript?
More exactly I want to use UDP sockets from  javascript. I know this is possible in Internet Explorer by using ActiveX, but I want to have the same thing for other browsers also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this isn't possible. It's outside JavaScript's scope. JavaScript is meant to run in the browser's sandbox for security reasons, and access to outside resources is strictly limited.

ActiveX controls are able to do this; *maybe* also Java Applets, although I don't know for sure.